# Rails Script Segmentation Fault with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I am getting a segmentation fault. Should `which ruby` return /usr/local/bin?

```
maletor$ rails generate mailer ContactMailer
    /Users/maletor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mysql2-0.2.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: [BUG] **Segmentation fault**
    ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Abort trap

maletor$ which rails
/usr/bin/rails

maletor$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/maletor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/maletor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/maletor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/maletor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0
     - /Users/maletor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => false
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "-n/usr/local/bin"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

maletor$ echo $PATH
/Users/maletor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/maletor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin:/Users/maletor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/maletor/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

maletor$ which gem
/Users/maletor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/gem

maletor$ ls ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/
erb gem irb rake    rdoc    ri  ruby    testrb

maletor$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.0

maletor$ which rails
/usr/bin/rails
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a problem with you RVM installation. `which` should return

```
/Users/maletor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
```

Upgrade to the latest RVM installation. There was a bug in the 1.0 release with "shell path caching".

```
$ rvm get head
$ rvm reload
$ rvm repair all
$ rvm use 1.9.2
```

Comment: maletor$ which rails returns /usr/bin/rails. Is this ok? Because I am still getting seg faults after I did the repair.

Comment: No, it should return the path under RVM, assuming you are using 1.9.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after struggling almost I found the right solution.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it was enough to run: rvm repair all

Comment: The syntax for updating RVM has changed to `rvm get {latest|x.y.z|head|master|branch|help}`. In my case updating to `stable` fixed the segmentation fault I was running in to, where updating to `head` only seemed to cause more problems.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti could you update the comment to deal with the new syntax?  rvm get head

Comment: I just closed my terminal and reopened it